# mysql chokes on certain characters and mssql not

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

What's a good way to filter string data so that we don't get a fatal error at an insert operation like this?

```
ERROR: SQL FAILS: Incorrect string value: '\x92s]' for column 'looseterm' at row 1

Failing SQL is INSERT INTO `looseterms` (`looseterm`) VALUES ('[loose_terms:indonesia’s]')
```

Does anyone know what the heck `'\x92s]'` is and what is it so dear to mysql to choke on it? 
Ms-Sql got no problems with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your [connection character set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-connection.html) to that in which your literals are encoded.  For example, for `UTF-8`:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
```

If different literals are in different encodings, you can specify the character set of those not in the connection character set with an [introducer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-literals.html):

```
INSERT INTO ... (_utf8'[loose_terms:...');
```

Comment: eggyal, is SET NAMES 'utf8' a sql statement that I need to run as soon as I get a $dbh ( database handle )? Or is that something that needs to be run at server level thru phpmyadmin or something?

Comment: @AverageJoe: Yes, it's a SQL command; execute it prior to your `INSERT` statement (on the same connection).

Comment: That insert statement is running 10,000 plus times cause it's in a while loop. Can't that be done once and for all at the top? BTW, I tried this `mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");` as soon as I get the $dbh, which is the same $dbh that the `insert` uses but I got no luck with it cause it died on the same indonesia spot again! But I did not do the _utf8 wrapper yet when I tried that. Is both needed? your original answer seemed like one or the other.

Comment: @AverageJoe: You only need one or the other.  You need not `SET NAMES` on every iteration through your loop - immediately on opening the connection (which should be before the loop begins) is enough.  `UTF-8` was an example... I don't know what character set your literals are actually in.

Comment: @AverageJoe: Also, in what character set is your `looseterm` column stored?  If it is not capable of storing the desired character, it'll complain even if the connection character set is correct.

Comment: Well, I tried this too; `mysql_set_charset('utf8',$dbh)`; and that too was tried right after getting the $dbh connection. It's not helping. I think it's the `’` that my-sql is choking on. It's in the string `indonesia’s`. Isn't this English char set? I'm not sure why mentioned  what character set my literals are actually in. The content I'm working with is submitted by tons of web users - the content is supposed to be in English cause it's an Eng. site. They were taken into ms-sql no problem. I was reading those records from ms-sql and inserting into ms-sql. That's how I ended up with the prob

Comment: @AverageJoe: That character is [U+2019](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm) ("RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK"), which is not available in many character sets.  I recommend you alter your table so that the `looseterm` column is in a character set capable of storing such characters, such as `UTF-8`.

Comment: So what to do? how do we complete the insert operation? Is there a PHP or mysql filter that would weed out those and the like?

Comment: @AverageJoe: Having checked [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/charset_support.htm), it looks like your current encoding of that character as `0x92` is likely to be the `windows-1252` character set (which MySQL calls `latin1`).  Try `SET NAMES 'latin1'`?

Comment: I'm gonna try that. But let me tell you, you are God-sent.

Comment: 10218 records got inserted. No choking. All I did was `blp_sql_go($dbh,"set names 'latin1'"); `. Basically replacing utf8 ( which is supposed to be the default ) did the trick thanks to you. but I now wonder what the consequences are in switching char sets from utf8 to latin1 at $dbh level? latin1 is a single byte too right? I remember reading some stuff over multi-byte characters and mysql_real_escape_string combination ending up with a deadly SQL injection situation - when char sets are played with. Do you recall that? Are we safe here with latin1? I'll add the link to next comment'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10904/discussion-between-eggyal-and-average-joe)