# Load data Infile Issue in MySQL(Incorrect String Value Error)

Tags: mysql, sql, load-data-infile

I am trying to insert data(24,000+ rows)from a text file to a MySQL table.
I am using following `Load Data Infile` query which reads data from `empdump.txt` & inserts it in a table called `o_master_employees` in MYSQL.

Query Is:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'empdump.txt' 
INTO TABLE o_master_employees 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

But here I'm facing with a error which is:

```
Incorrect string value: '\x92s MS ...' for column 'PID_DESCR' at row 101
```

I've checked with the data in PID_DESCR column & data is `FedEX's MS Prod Support`

Can u please help me to identify what this error is about & what can be the solution???

Thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: I'm not 100% this is a duplicate, but this might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457341/mysql-chokes-on-certain-characters-and-mssql-not.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in UTF-8 you might have success with

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'empdump.txt' 
CHARACTER SET utf8
INTO TABLE o_master_employees 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

(I added the CHARACTER SET line.)

Comment: Thanx for your answer......I've tried with this query but error still remains....Not actually getting what is "\x92s MS ..." :(

Comment: I'm thinking that error is occurring because of single quote mark in "FedEX's MS Prod Support" data in column PID_DESCR. I've also tried with ESCAPED BY '\'' statement in the same query but no luck..!!

Comment: \x92s means that there is a character which is 0x92 in hexadecimal followed by a s character.

Comment: Can you try with `latin1` instead of `utf8` perhaps your data is in Latin1 encoding. Or do you know in which encoding your data is?

Comment: yes peschu....My data is in utf8 encoding.I've checked with it. But still no luck !

Comment: Then I guess your encoding is Latin1 and not UTF-8 :)

Comment: (And if you accept my answer, then others can see that it is useful.)

Comment: Yes u r right.....my encoding is latin1 ... :) done with inserting 24k+ data... :) thanks again....